# What do we call the class of geometries $n-2$ and lower in $\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

A hyperplane is of dimension $n-1$.

What about $n-2$, $n-3$, etc...?

What do we call these geometrically?

Comment: They're subspaces...

Comment: Subspaces are linear.

Comment: I was taught to call them "flats" many years ago, when I took third-semester calculus, but I've never seen or heard the term since.  Too bad; it's a good name.

Comment: What do you mean by "class of geometries"? Are only points, lines, and planes admissible for $n=3$? For instance, is a circular curve admissible? What about a non-continuous curve?